# Array refuses to be returned with values

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, persistence

I am trying to get data from my persistencejs(this is a library!) database in javascript. I am getting the values and pushing them in the array, I'm doing this in a forEach loop. In the loop the array is being filled with values, I have confirmed this using alerts.

But when I look at the array outside of the loop, it's empty. Why is this?

Here's the code (I've tried putting the variable inside the function, and tried changing it to this.newDataArray as well.):

```
var newDataArray = new Array();
function getData(){

    dataTable.all().list(function(tasks){
        tasks.forEach(function (r) {
            var tTank1 = r.Tank1;
            var tTank2 = r.Tank2;
            var tTank3 = r.Tank3;
            var tTank4 = r.Tank4;
            var tHelicopter = r.Helicopter;
            newDataArray.push(tTank1, tTank2, tTank3, tTank4, tHelicopter);
            alert(newDataArray);
        });
    });
    alert(newDataArray);
    return newDataArray
}
```

Here I am just testing the return value in a method that's being executed:

```
Data.prototype.fetchData = function(csv){
    jQuery.get(csv, function(data) {
        var result = $.csv.toArrays(data);
        result.shift();
        result.forEach(function (r) {
            var joinedResult = r.join();
            fillDB(joinedResult);
        });
    });
    alert(getData());
};
```

So I'm hoping anyone knows the answer to this? Also other criticism about my code and/or post format are welcome as well :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably not that the data isn't being populated, but that you're alerting it too soon.

jQuery's `get` is an asynchronous call, and it returns before the callback has processed.  If you move the alert inside the `get` call, you should have your data.

```
Data.prototype.fetchData = function(csv){
    jQuery.get(csv, function(data) {
        var result = $.csv.toArrays(data);
        result.shift();
        result.forEach(function (r) {
            var joinedResult = r.join();
            fillDB(joinedResult);
        });
        alert(getData());
    });
};
```

Comment: It's true that I've been struggling with these asynchronous calls, this is my first project in javascript. But I am not sure which part of the get call you mean?

Comment: Notice that my sample moved the `alert` call inside the function supplied to `get`?  That's what I was talking about.  The `get` call returns immediately.  Later, when the server returns its data, your callback function will be invoked.  That's when you can comfortably do an alert.

Comment: Yes I noticed it, but sadly it did not work for me. And thanks for these replies so far.
-edit: Maybe I should mention that if I move the return up as in:
> function getData(){
> var newDataArray = new Array();
> dataTable.all().list(function(tasks){
>     tasks.forEach(function (r) {
>         var tTank1 = r.Tank1;
>         var tTank2 = r.Tank2;
>         var tTank3 = r.Tank3;
>         var tTank4 = r.Tank4;
>         var tHelicopter = r.Helicopter;
>         newDataArray.push(tTank1, tTank2, tTank3, tTank4, >tHelicopter);
>     });
>     return newDataArray
>    });
>}
It alerts "undefined"

Comment: I think we need to see more of the code, then.  How are `fillDB` and `getData` related?  What is `$.csv.toArrays` ?  And what are you calling first to start this off?

Comment: Here I was trying to make the code looking more decent, but I seem to be doing it wrong :p. fillDB is a method that is being executed while the page loads, I have chosen to put the getData in this method because it is being executed on load, but later on in the project I need to be able to call getData for my formula's, so the method needs to be used in other methods for calculations. 

the "$.csv.toArrays" is from a library called "jquery.csv-0.71.js". This library is being used to load csv formatted context into an array.

Comment: But I guess the question is whether `fillDB` updates the global `dataTable` variable that `getData` relies on as its source of information.  If not, then how does that get created, and are you doing your alert before the `dataTable` variable is available?  (I have other objections to this as a global variable, but that's besides the point for now.)

Comment: fillDB updates the dataTable. but dataTable is not a normal variable(I think).
code:
[code]
Data.prototype.createDataTable = function(name, csv){
 dataTable = persistence.define(name, {
  Tank1: "INT",
  Tank2: "INT",
  Tank3: "INT",
  Tank4: "INT",
  Helicopter: "INT",
  });
  this.fetchData(csv);
};
[/code]
But if I alert the array right after pushing the values in it, it returns the correct values. So I know the dataTable has been filled before I'm getting the data from it.

Comment: I don't know if I can cancel that chat request, as my company is blocking chat...

Comment: Is the code small enough to put in a Fiddle or JSBin?  I'm guessing this is something small, but I don't think we can diagnose it like this.

Comment: Which chat request? If you have send any request of the kind, I have not received anything in my inbox or notifications.

Comment: I clicked the "automatically move this to chat" link, and my company's firewall blocked me from getting there.  But the link to the chat appeared as a comment that I could still edit, so I replaced it with what you saw.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Well there's quite a couple of classes involved, and some libaries. So I could put the code in it, but it would not be able to run.

Comment: So post as much as you can.  And both Fiddle and JSBin allow you to link to libraries that have public urls... so you might be able to run it.

Comment: I mean that I have downloaded the libaries, and it is an local csv file as well. Should I compress it and upload it instead?

Comment: I believe both have a technique to deal with AJAX.  I know that JSBin does.  But for a first pass, just post the non-working code, so that it's all in one spot.  And don't worry about it not running.

Comment: I don't see an option to create new files in JSBin? Do you want me to paste the code all underneath each other? I am sorry for this, but this is the first time I have heard of JSBin, this will really come in handy, so thanks for showing me!

Comment: Yes, just put it all together.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ojivod/1/edit This should be it. It looks very messy in my eyes so I'm hoping you'll be able to use this.
I also must apologize for the lack of comments. I am doing this in a group project, and my partner does not want us to add comments yet...

Comment: Is the problem as simple as mismatched capitalization?  In the HTML body tag, you have `onload="main.load()"`, but your code has `function Main() { /* ... */ }` and `Main.prototype.load = /* ... */`.  Could that be the (ahem) main problem?

Comment: As far as we have understood this is the javascript way of object-oriënted programming in javascript. We have made the "Class" Main, and are giving it multiple methods by using the ".prototype.". And above we fill the variable "main" with the class "new Main()", on which we can call the methods like load(), by typing main.load. Is there something more hidden behind this that I am not aware of? Nice pun ;)

Comment: No, you have it right.  I simply missed the the script tag higher in the HTML.  So that's not it....  hmmm ....

Comment: By the way trying something like http://pastebin.com/B47W8DwH but this alerts an empty array as well

Comment: ... but your dataTable object is actually populated?

Comment: If I put the alert after I have pushed the values in it's alerting the correct values, so yes it is populated.

Comment: This shows when it does, and when it does not alert the proper/any value. http://pastebin.com/dvFVAseA. I'm guessing since the dataTable.all are a function from another library (persistencejs) these might block any other methods? But I'm not sure since there's also a forEach loop being used which works, but that might be part of the method from the library. I'm not sure if there are any possible limitations on these functions, since the library has been chosen by our teacher, but contains barely to no documentation. Nor can I find helpfull information about these methods anywhere.

Comment: I've tried this : http://pastebin.com/iRNM10Mi , which alerts an undefined object. I know this probably isn't the correct way, but I'm just trying to give you as much information as possible. I think making us work with 2 barely documented libraries and jQuery, while having to handle data and use localStorage might not have been the best starter project for javascript...

Comment: Just took a look at your site, felt like I had to mention I'm aware they're not classes but constructors, hence why I but them in between the ", I know this has no relevance to this question, just trying to save some skin :P

Comment: Sorry, actually job distracting me from interesting discussion.  :-)  I'm wondering if the callback to `dataTable.all().list` does not supply array parameters but instead individual items.  Maybe you could try: `testArray = dataTable.all().list(function(tasks){alert($.isArray(tasks));});

Comment: As in :

"function getData(){
 var newDataArray = dataTable.all().list(function(tasks){alert($.isArray(tasks));})
}"?
This alerted true :)

PS. Thanks for helping me out while on the job :) I really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm afraid I have to call it a day now :( And I know that the arrays are being filled inside the loop, it's just outside the loop that that the array seems to be empty which is really weird.. I will get back to this tomorrow. Thank you for all the effort :) I will be back here tomorrow afternoon.