# It says the array is undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, return, undefined

In my code I am filling an array through another method in a for loop. I have verified that the arrays have actually been filled with the correct information, but when I try to return and use the it says there it is undefined, but why?

Code:

```
function Data(name, csv){
    this.dataTable = null;
    this.createDataTable(name, csv);
}

Data.prototype.createDataTable = function(name, csv){
    dataTable = persistence.define(name, {
        Tank1: "INT",
        Tank2: "INT",
        Tank3: "INT",
        Tank4: "INT",
        Helicopter: "INT",
    });
    this.fetchData(csv);
};

Data.prototype.fetchData = function(csv){
    jQuery.get(csv, function(data) {
        var result = $.csv.toArrays(data);
        result.shift();
        result.forEach(function (r) {
            var joinedResult = r.join();
            fillDB(joinedResult);
        });
    });

    var test = getData();  <--- This is where I am testing the code.
    var joinedResult = testlolol.join();
    var splitData = joinedResult.split(";");
    alert(splitData);
};

//This function will fill the database using the parsed array line from the csv file.
function fillDB(DataArray){
    //Wipe local database clean
    persistence.reset(function(){
        //Write schema
        persistence.schemaSync(function(){
            //Add values from the array to their matching columns.
            var data = new dataTable();
            var splitData = DataArray.split(";");
            data.Tank1 = splitData[0];
            data.Tank2 = splitData[1];
            data.Tank3 = splitData[2];
            data.Tank4 = splitData[3];
            data.Helicopter = splitData[4];
            persistence.add(data);
            persistence.flush();
        });
    });
}

function deleteData(column, operator, value){
      persistence.flush(function(){
       dataTable.all().filter(column,operator , value).destroyAll();
      });
}

function addData(Tank1, Tank2, Tank3, Tank4, Helicopter){
        var data = new dataTable();
        data.Tank1 = Tank1;
        data.Tank2 = Tank2;
        data.Tank3 = Tank3;
        data.Tank4 = Tank4;
        data.Helicopter = Helicopter;
        persistence.add(data);
        persistence.flush();
}

function getData(){
    var newDataArray = new Array();
    dataTable.all().list(function(tasks){
        tasks.forEach(function (r) {
            var tTank1 = r.Tank1;
            var tTank2 = r.Tank2;
            var tTank3 = r.Tank3;
            var tTank4 = r.Tank4;
            var tHelicopter = r.Helicopter;
            newDataArray.push(tTank1, tTank2, tTank3, tTank4, tHelicopter);
            tempTest(newDataArray); 
        });
    });
}

function tempTest(array){
    var newDataArray = new Array();
    newDataArray.push(array);
    alert(newDataArray);   <-- these contain the correct values
    return  newDataArray;
}
```

So I'm hoping anyone knows the answer to this? Also other criticism about my code and/or post format are welcome as well :)

Comment: you do not return anything inside `getData()`

Comment: I didn't find a place, where your array is undefined.

Comment: Arghhh! Khanh To is right, this is my mistake. I have been struggling with a different before ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992837/array-refuses-to-be-returned-with-values/17993039 ) so I've lost sight on the situation. Sorry for the dumb mistake..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning any value

```
function getData(){
    var newDataArray = new Array();
    dataTable.all().list(function(tasks){
        tasks.forEach(function (r) {
            var tTank1 = r.Tank1;
            var tTank2 = r.Tank2;
            var tTank3 = r.Tank3;
            var tTank4 = r.Tank4;
            var tHelicopter = r.Helicopter;
            newDataArray.push(tTank1, tTank2, tTank3, tTank4, tHelicopter);
            tempTest(newDataArray); 
        });
    });
    return newDataArray 
}
```

Comment: Yes or so I noticed :( But that return does not work by the way. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992837/array-refuses-to-be-returned-with-values.
But yes that's the answer to this question.